# Profiling Python Scripts running on Mod_wsgi

Tags: python, profiling, wsgi

How can I profile a python script running on mod_wsgi on apache

I would like to use cProfile but it seems it requires me to invoke a function manually. Is there a way to enable cProfile globally and have it keep on logging results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to wrap you wsgi application function inside another function that just calls your function using cProfile and use that as the application. Or you can reuse existing WSGI middleware to do that for you, for example [repoze.profile](http://repoze.org/repoze_components.html) does pretty much what you seem to want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the WSGI profile middleware for [WHIFF](http://whiff.sourceforge.net) (currently only available from the mercurial repository):
[profile.py](http://aaron.oirt.rutgers.edu/cgi-bin/whiffRepo.cgi/file/3929e9c62c84/whiff/middleware/profile.py).  That should get you started.  If you want to modify it to run outside of the WHIFF context change the line

```
 gateway.putResource(env, resourcePath, report)
```

to something like

```
 file("/tmp/profile.txt", "w").write(report)
```